# simplifies to vs. be simplified to?

Tags: mathematics, active-vs-passive

In mathematics, one often simplifies an expression.

In the mathematical writing, which one is correct (or more natural)?

Equation (1) is simplified to Equation (2).

vs.

Equation (1) simplifies to Equation (2).

It seems that both are used in papers.

Comment: "is simplified to" implies that the equestion is being simplified in this context. "simplifies to" says something more general about the nature equation. There is no real difference in meaning but this might help with which might be more natural in any given context.